# Router won't forward ranges of ports to Linux server. Is there a software solution?

Tags: linux, router, port-forwarding, iptables, asterisk

I need to forward a large range of ports to a Linux machine running Asterisk. The machine is behind a household router. The router can be successful configured to forward single ports to Asterisk, e.g., 5060, however the ability to forward a range of ports such 10000:20000 has been disabled on the router, apparently, by my telephone/internet carrier, the provider of the device.

[image: Port forwarding page]

The router's firewall does allow for a range of ports to be opened and internal/external IPs and ports to be assigned. At least, it does so  without any apparent error.

[image: Firewall]

I don't understand the function of the internal port and IP on the router's firewall. Is there a way for my linux machine on the assigned IP to do it's own port forwarding to Asterisk?

Changing the router will be a major inconvenience. I hope someone can help point to a software solution. With iptables, perhaps?

Thank you,

Comment: Does the Linux machine have its own public IP address (by "its own" I basically mean "visible in `ip addr`"), or does the entire household share a single IP address at the router?

Comment: The Linux machine has an MAC address-reserved IP, done by the router. All internal devices have the same external IP and I'm accessing that via dynamic DNS. Thanks

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the port-forwarding feature, **and** of the part where "The router's firewall does allow for a range of ports to be opened and internal/external IPs and ports to be assigned"?

Comment: You can see in the port forwarding section that ranges are offered, however when a range like 8080:9090 is entered, as given in their example, it responds with an error. See: https://ufile.io/341ijlss  See also the Firewall section. This gives no error when a range is entered: https://ufile.io/g7px7fbp

Comment: It's a Brazilian router and I've Googled to find others complaining of the same thing and with no solution given

Comment: Sometimes, in the “destination port” field, you are only expected to put in the starting port of a range. // Only the router can do the port forwarding.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel B, that's it! While I'd tried leaving the the destination port blank, I hadn't thought of entering the starting point for the range only. It works. What a relief! Thanks again.

Comment: @sebinho What happens when you attempt to forward external ports `10000:20000` to the IP of the machine running Asterisk?  Generally speaking, ISPs can't block port forwarding, as a modem has no clue about port redirects and does not speak the same language as a router.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have option send ports one-by-one. You need like 2 ports for each channel, no need many. Change rtp.conf after that for same values.

In most cases you just have search DMZ ip setting on that router, set it to asterisk internal ip and do firewall on server.

Answer (score 0):

> The router can be successful configured to forward single ports to Asterisk, eg. 5060, however the ability to forward a range of ports such 10000:20000 has been disabled on the router

According to the screenshot, you should only enter the *external* port range. The 'Internal Port' field is labelled as optional in this situation, and internal ports will automatically be mapped 1:1 to the same range.

*(Unrelated side note: The label says "if the source is…" but that's not correct – both the 'Internal' and 'External' fields refer to the destination address/port.)*

> The router's firewall does allow for a range of ports to be opened and internal/external IPs and ports to be assigned. At least, it does so without any apparent error.

'Port Forward' rules control packet *rewriting* – the "External" fields are used for matching the original value, while the "Internal" fields" are used to specify the *new* (rewritten) value. If the original port value is specified as a range, the new value naturally has to be a range of the exact same size, which is why the router doesn't even allow entering it.

In contrast, 'Firewall' rules control packet *filtering* – all boxes match the corresponding existing fields in the IP packet. The "Remote" (aka Source) values are completely independent from the "Local" (aka Destination) values.

> I don't understand the function of the internal port and IP on the router's firewall.

The firewall can apply to other packets, not just those coming from WAN through port-forwarding. Some routers allow multiple independent LAN subnets to be created – the firewall would then also control traffic between subnets.

For example, you might allow a TV on the 'IoT' subnet to access your fileserver on the 'main LAN' subnet – in this case the TV (source) would be the "remote" device and the fileserver (destination) would be the "local" device.

#### About port forwarding

> Is there a way for my linux machine on the assigned IP to do it's own port forwarding to Asterisk?

Your Linux machine cannot bypass the router using only software.

Technically speaking, the machine already always forwards packets to services running on it. But your problem isn't that – the problem is that those packets could not reach *the machine itself*.

When you say "All internal devices have the same external IP", that usually means *none* of them actually have it. Your router is the only device which does, and all inbound packets for the external IP address must arrive at the router first, both physically and logically.

Some routers have a feature called "DMZ" which is like a port-forwarding rule to be used if none of the actual port-forwarding rules matched. If you can configure the Linux machine as the "DMZ host" it will then receive *all* connections that weren't already configured otherwise.

But if you have neither port-forwarding nor DMZ, then there is no way for your internal machine to "steal" packets from the router – it simply won't receive them.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. The problem is resolved. Please see my last comment in the above.

Comment: If you found a different solution (or if Daniel B isn't going to post their own), you can post and accept an answer even if it's for your own thread.

Comment: seems i can only mark it as resolved in 24h but will do so

Answer (score 0):

Putting an answer here to say that the problems was resolved with Daniel B's suggestion (in the comments above) of entering on the starting point only of the port range in the internal field of the forwarding configuration.

Thanks very much for all the answers and comments above, I've learnt a lot from them.